# how to split date and time and create separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I want to split **DATE_H_REAL** and create two columns. one for date and one hour, i use this :

```
from datetime import datetime
df_picru = datetime.strptime(df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df_picru['day'] = df_picru.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_picru['hour'] = df_picru.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

My data look like this

```
0                      NaN
1                      NaN
2                      NaN
3        02/02/2016 16:16
4        02/02/2016 16:17
5        02/02/2016 16:18
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) - if need output as `strings`:

```
df_picru = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_H_REAL':['02/02/2016 16:16',
                                        '02/02/2016 16:17', np.nan]})

df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'])
df_picru['day'] = df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_picru['hour'] = df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df_picru)
          DATE_H_REAL         day      hour
0 2016-02-02 16:16:00  2016-02-02  16:16:00
1 2016-02-02 16:17:00  2016-02-02  16:17:00
2                 NaT         NaT       NaT

print (type(df_picru.loc[0, 'day']))
<class 'str'>

print (type(df_picru.loc[0, 'hour']))
<class 'str'>

print (df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'].dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

Or [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) + [`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) if need output `python date` and `python time`:

```
df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'])
df_picru['day'] = df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'].dt.date
df_picru['hour'] = df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'].dt.time
print (df_picru)
          DATE_H_REAL         day      hour
0 2016-02-02 16:16:00  2016-02-02  16:16:00
1 2016-02-02 16:17:00  2016-02-02  16:17:00
2                 NaT         NaN       NaN

print (type(df_picru.loc[0, 'day']))
<class 'datetime.date'>

print (type(df_picru.loc[0, 'hour']))
<class 'datetime.time'>

print (df_picru['DATE_H_REAL'].dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```